# jQuery get dimensions of image via its reference

Tags: jquery

I'm loading an html with references to images

How do I retrieve the real pixel width and height of each image referenced?

```
    // loaded html:
    <div id="eleWithImgs">
        <img id="ph01" src=".../image01.jpg">
        <img id="ph02" src=".../image02.jpg">
        ...

    // JS:
('#parentEle').load('.../photos.html #eleWithImgs', function() {

    $('#eleWithImgs').children().each(function() {

        var origWidth = // get dimensions of the image

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for the image to load before you can get the dimensions

```
$('#eleWithImgs').children().each(function() {
    this.onload = function() {
        var origWidth = this.clientWidth;
    }
    if(this.complete) this.onload();
});
```

Comment: I just edited my post. I am calling this on load end right? Still I'm getting 0's

Comment: oh no wait... it's end of html load not the image, let me try your way

Comment: That's not a load event, that is the load() method, which is a shortcut for ajax, and has nothing to do with when the images have loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.height()` and `.width()` functions to get the width/height of those images.

Try,

```
$('#eleWithImgs').children().each(function() {
    var origWidth = $(this).width();
    var origHeight = $(this).height();
});
```

Comment: I've tried that and it ends up with 0 for all... I thought it could be because the children are <img>s not the image file itself...?

Comment: @user3024007 Have you tried this code inside the .load event.?